# Express React Views - how to manually render

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views

I want to use something like this to render some html, but I'm not rendering my html in the context of a 'web server' at all - I'm not trying to hook it up to an express server at all.

I'm running some node code periodically that should output html to files, and so really what I want is something that I can call a function like this:

```
const html = renderTemplate({userName: 'George'});
```

and it will pass in `userName` as React props to whatever express-react-view React component I've set up, and return to me the html.

But all the examples and guides show how to set up express-react-views as a rendering engine in express.js, not just if you want to have a standalone function that renders html.

I'd also be fine with using a different package altogether that will allow me to use React jsx templates and render them into html, without the context of a browser.

Comment: Something like [`rendertostring`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html

https://medium.com/@remarkablemark/passing-props-in-a-universal-react-web-app-c52aca48c36b

npm requirements:

```
npm install react react-dom
npm install @babel/core @babel/register
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react
```

here's my main node file, `entry.js`

```
require("@babel/register")({
    presets: ["@babel/preset-react"]
});

const Index = require('./views/index.jsx');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
var React = require('react');


var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
    React.createElement(Index, {title:'title'})
);
```

Then, in `/views/index.jsx` :

```
var React = require('react');
var PropTypes = require('prop-types');

function countTo(n) {
    var a = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a.push(i + 1);
    }
    return a.join(', ');
}

class Index extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <body>
                <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
                <p>Welcome to {this.props.title}</p>
                <p>
                    I can count to 10:
                    {countTo(10)}
                </p>
            </body>
        );
    }
}

Index.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string,
};

module.exports = Index;
```